# Compression of an image on an iPhone like on WhatsApp

Tags: ios, swift, compression

I'm trying to find an image compression algorithm in the Swift programming language, as in the WhatsApp messenger. In the programming language Java under OS Android I found quickly, and under the platform iOS have difficulties.

Here is the image compression algorithm for Android:

```
public static File saveBitmapToFile(File file){
    try {
        // BitmapFactory options to downsize the image
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        o.inSampleSize = 6;
        // factor of downsizing the image

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        //Bitmap selectedBitmap = null;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o);
        inputStream.close();

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=75;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while(o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE &&
                o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) {
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        Bitmap selectedBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, o2);
        inputStream.close();

        // here i override the original image file
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        selectedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70 , outputStream);

        return file;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This algorithm compresses the image to 100 KB. If you can tell me how to duplicate this code into the Swift programming language, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress an UIImage by using UIImageJPEGRepresentation method. Following example shows 0.4 compression ratio.

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)! //image is your original image
let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)
```

Comment: I already tried to do so using 0.01 coefficient with the width and length of the image 600x600, but iphone 5 the image from the camera was compressed to 400 kb, and on the iphone 8 to 600 kb. The image was just photographed!

Answer (score 0):

This function should do it:

```
func compressImage(_ image: UIImage?) -> UIImage? {
var actualHeight = Float(image?.size.height ?? 0.0)
var actualWidth = Float(image?.size.width ?? 0.0)
let maxHeight: Float = 600.0
let maxWidth: Float = 800.0
var imgRatio: Float = actualWidth / actualHeight
let maxRatio: Float = maxWidth / maxHeight
let compressionQuality: Float = 0.5 //50 percent compression

if actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth {
    if imgRatio < maxRatio {
        //adjust width according to maxHeight
        imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight
        actualWidth = imgRatio * actualWidth
        actualHeight = maxHeight
    } else if imgRatio > maxRatio {
        //adjust height according to maxWidth
        imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth
        actualHeight = imgRatio * actualHeight
        actualWidth = maxWidth
    } else {
        actualHeight = maxHeight
        actualWidth = maxWidth
    }
}

    let rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(actualWidth), height: CGFloat(actualHeight))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size)
    image?.draw(in: rect)
    let img: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    let imageData = img?.jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat(compressionQuality))
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    if let imageData = imageData {
        return UIImage(data: imageData)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Usage:

`secondHighest.image = compressImage(image, quality: 0.0)`//you could always add a parameter like this to controll quality

```
Highest.image = compressImage(image, quality: 0.6)//bottom
```

---

result:

[image]